# ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter does not show content

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the Fragment, ViewPager & co. from the Android support library v4. Fragments seem to scroll when I listen to page change events from the pager but the content is not visible. What I basically have is:

A FragmentActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        FragmentPagerAdapter fpa = new MyPagerAdapter(this, createFragments());

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        vp.setAdapter(fpa);
    }

    private List<Fragment> createFragments() {
        List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        list.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, First.class.getName()));
        list.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Second.class.getName()));
        list.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Third.class.getName()));

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    }
```

A FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragments.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view.equals(o);
    }

}
```

And three Fragments that look like this:

```
public class First extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

And they have layout like these:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:text="First Fragment"
              android:id="@+id/firstText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I originally forgot to add the main layout, here it comes:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: could you provide the layout which contains the viewpager? Have you put a breakpoint in getItem() just to make sure its firing? Also, set the textcolor to white on those textviews just to make sure!

Comment: oh yeah, added that now.

Comment: Your viewpager has it's height set to wrap content, and it's pages have their height set to fill parent - this doesn't make sense and probably means your pages are taking up no space. I suspect you want the viewpager to have a height of fill_parent as well.

Comment: I have set the ViewPager to fill_parent and manually set the text color of the TextView's to #ffffff but no luck. Still nothing is visible.

Comment: Not much else I can really see from here, feel free to zip up the project and send it to me, i don't mind having a look - dw86@kent.ac.uk

Comment: I rewrote the whole thing from scratch and now works perfectly. Must be something with the position of the stars in the sky.

Comment: @rgngl I still get wrong from the post. How do you rewrote your code?
Can you please provide it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is because you have overridden `isViewFromObject` in `MyPagerAdapter`.

`FragmentPagerAdapter` handles `isViewFromObject`, so you shouldnt override it.

As with me, I reckon most visitors to this post started with a basic `PagerAdapter`,  then realised they needed to page fragments and changed their base class without realising the consequences. Unfortunate, but I couldn't criticise the Android team for this.

Comment: I changed from a simple PagerAdapter to a FragmentPagerAdapter and didn't realize this issue. Thanks so much.

Comment: life saver, i don't find this info anywhere else...!

Comment: wow, I've done this 100 times successfully and suddenly had this problem and couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

Ya correct as Ian Newson told, just remove isViewFromObject overrided method from your code

```
  @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return false;
   }
```